# What is the way to initialize a function with classes in the main file?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, program-entry-point, cout

This program is a c++ project to create a barn of animal using classes for the barn and animals.  The animals are identified by their name, type, and weight. At a specified time, the animals will eat and gain weight. The user has the option to choose how many day periods will pass. Most of the code has been written, now it is a matter of getting main to work with the class functions. When I try to do functions in main, I get the error code "main.cpp:117:28: error: ‘class Animal’ has no member named ‘display’" with respect to the line that states:  cout << barn[i]->display()
Here is the code.

```cpp
// C++ program to create classes for Barn of Animals
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //I need to run the program so a unit of time passes
    //When the time runs, the time will be compared to
    //the animals feeding time.  When that feed time passes, 
    //The animal gains weight and the new weight is shown.
    int choice;

    cout << "1) Simulate Days" << endl;
    cout << "2) Display Animals" << endl;
    cout << "3) Exit" << endl;

    cout << "Choose an option: \n";
    cout << "Enter 1, 2 or 3: ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "Choice 1";
            break;  //Here we will run feedAnimal
        case 2:
            cout << "Choice 2";
            break;  //Here we will display all the animals
        case 3:
            cout << "Choice 3";
            break;  //Here we will exit the program
        default:
            cout << "Not 1, 2 or 3";
            break;
    }
}

// base Animal class
class Animal
{
    private:
        // data members
        string type;
    string name;
    int weight;
    public:
        // constructor to initialize the members to specified values
        Animal(string type, string name, int weight): type(type), name(name), weight(weight) {}

    // getters
    string getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    int getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    // setter for weight
    void setWeight(int weight)
    {
        this->weight = weight;
    }
};

// derived class Horse
class Horse: public Animal
{
    public: Horse(string name, int weight): Animal("horse", name, weight) {}
};

// derived class Cow
class Cow: public Animal
{
    public: Cow(string name, int weight): Animal("cow", name, weight) {}
};

// derived class Chicken
class Chicken: public Animal
{
    public: Chicken(string name, int weight): Animal("chicken", name, weight) {}
};

class Barn
{
    private:
        vector<Animal*> barn;

    public:
        Barn();
    void feedAnimal();

};

Barn::Barn()
{
    srand(time(0)); // this will be srand not rand
    Animal * a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a = new Horse("Artax" + to_string(i + 1), rand() % 200 + 1820); // end with semicolon not colon
        barn.push_back(a);

        a = new Cow("Fafnir" + to_string(i + 1), rand() % 250 + 1200);  // convert (i+1) to string not (i+)
        barn.push_back(a);

        a = new Chicken("David" + to_string(i + 1), rand() % 2 + 15);
        barn.push_back(a);

        for (int i = 0; i < barn.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << barn[i]->display() << " " << " ";   //This Displays all the animals

        }
    }

    void Barn::feedAnimal()
    {
        int days;   // = 0;
        cout << "how many days:";
        cin >> days;

        for (int day = 0; day < days; day++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                string feed = to_string(i) + ":00"; // define the type for feed

                cout << "The Time is " << feed << "\n";

                if (i == 3) // time is 3:00, feed the chickens
                {
                    // loop over the vector of Animals to feed the Chicken
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < barn.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (barn[i]->getType() == "chicken")    // this animal is chicken
                            barn[i]->setWeight(barn[i]->getWeight() + 1);   // add 1 pound to its weight
                        cout << name << " " << type << " now weighs " << getweight() << " lbs";
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 5)    // time is 5:00, feed the horses
                {
                    // loop over the vector of Animals to feed the Horse
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < barn.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (barn[i]->getType() == "horse")  // this animal is horse

                            barn[i]->setWeight(barn[i]->getWeight() + 5);   // add 5 pound to its weight
                        cout << name << " " << type << " now weighs " << getweight() << " lbs";
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 7)    // time is 7:00, feed the cows
                {
                    // loop over the vector of Animals to feed the Cow
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < barn.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (barn[i]->getType() == "cow")    // this animal is cow
                            barn[i]->setWeight(barn[i]->getWeight() + 5);   // add 5 pound to its weight
                        cout << name << " " << type << " now weighs " << getweight() << " lbs";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is not lying.  There is no such function in `class Animal`.  The other problem is that you're declaring all these classes after the main function so if you try to use them in main, then you'll get errors due to the compiler having never seen them.  It would be worth spending some time to properly indent your code.  Do that while writing it.  As currently written it is basically unreadable.

Comment: Instead of a `display` function, consider overloading `operator<<()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing a completely separate function, this is how operator << can be overloaded:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
    int i = 0;
public: 
    MyClass() : i(4) { }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, MyClass obj) {
        out << obj.i;
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass myClass;
    std::cout << myClass;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside class `Animal` you can just implement `display()` method that returns string and everything works after that change:

```cpp
std::string display() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "type: " << type << ", name: " << name
        << ", weights: " << weight << std::endl;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Full corrected code below. Also had to fix some typos to make code compilable:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/T1zY4os7P)

```cpp
// C++ program to create classes for Barn of Animals
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //I need to run the program so a unit of time passes
    //When the time runs, the time will be compared to
    //the animals feeding time.  When that feed time passes, 
    //The animal gains weight and the new weight is shown.
    int choice;

    cout << "1) Simulate Days" << endl;
    cout << "2) Display Animals" << endl;
    cout << "3) Exit" << endl;

    cout << "Choose an option: \n";
    cout << "Enter 1, 2 or 3: ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "Choice 1";
            break;  //Here we will run feedAnimal
        case 2:
            cout << "Choice 2";
            break;  //Here we will display all the animals
        case 3:
            cout << "Choice 3";
            break;  //Here we will exit the program
        default:
            cout << "Not 1, 2 or 3";
            break;
    }
}

// base Animal class
class Animal {
private:
    // data members
    string type;
    string name;
    int weight;

public:
    // constructor to initialize the members to specified values
    Animal(string type, string name, int weight): type(type), name(name), weight(weight) {}

    // getters
    string getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    int getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }

    // setter for weight
    void setWeight(int weight)
    {
        this->weight = weight;
    }

    std::string display() const {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "type: " << type << ", name: " << name
            << ", weights: " << weight << std::endl;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

// derived class Horse
class Horse: public Animal
{
    public: Horse(string name, int weight): Animal("horse", name, weight) {}
};

// derived class Cow
class Cow: public Animal
{
    public: Cow(string name, int weight): Animal("cow", name, weight) {}
};

// derived class Chicken
class Chicken: public Animal
{
    public: Chicken(string name, int weight): Animal("chicken", name, weight) {}
};

class Barn
{
private:
    vector<Animal*> barn;

public:
    Barn();
    void feedAnimal();
};

Barn::Barn() {
    srand(time(0)); // this will be srand not rand
    Animal * a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a = new Horse("Artax" + to_string(i + 1), rand() % 200 + 1820); // end with semicolon not colon
        barn.push_back(a);

        a = new Cow("Fafnir" + to_string(i + 1), rand() % 250 + 1200);  // convert (i+1) to string not (i+)
        barn.push_back(a);

        a = new Chicken("David" + to_string(i + 1), rand() % 2 + 15);
        barn.push_back(a);

        for (int i = 0; i < barn.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << barn[i]->display() << " " << " ";   //This Displays all the animals
        }
    }
}

void Barn::feedAnimal()
{
    int days;   // = 0;
    cout << "how many days:";
    cin >> days;

    for (int day = 0; day < days; day++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            string feed = to_string(i) + ":00"; // define the type for feed

            cout << "The Time is " << feed << "\n";

            if (i == 3) // time is 3:00, feed the chickens
            {
                // loop over the vector of Animals to feed the Chicken
                for (size_t i = 0; i < barn.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (barn[i]->getType() == "chicken")    // this animal is chicken
                        barn[i]->setWeight(barn[i]->getWeight() + 1);   // add 1 pound to its weight
                    //cout << name << " " << type << " now weighs " << getWeight() << " lbs";
                    cout << barn[i]->display();
                }
            }
            else if (i == 5)    // time is 5:00, feed the horses
            {
                // loop over the vector of Animals to feed the Horse
                for (size_t i = 0; i < barn.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (barn[i]->getType() == "horse")  // this animal is horse

                        barn[i]->setWeight(barn[i]->getWeight() + 5);   // add 5 pound to its weight
                    //cout << name << " " << type << " now weighs " << getWeight() << " lbs";
                    cout << barn[i]->display();
                }
            }
            else if (i == 7)    // time is 7:00, feed the cows
            {
                // loop over the vector of Animals to feed the Cow
                for (size_t i = 0; i < barn.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (barn[i]->getType() == "cow")    // this animal is cow
                        barn[i]->setWeight(barn[i]->getWeight() + 5);   // add 5 pound to its weight
                    //cout << name << " " << type << " now weighs " << getWeight() << " lbs";
                    cout << barn[i]->display();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here's how I got it to work. Thanks for all the assistance, it really helped me out.

```
//Fixed Practice code

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// base Animal class
class Animal {
private:
    // data members
    string type;
    string name;
    int weight;
public:
    // constructor to initialize the members to specified values
    //Animal(string type, string name, int weight) : type(type), name(name), weight(weight)
    Animal(string type, string name, int weight) {
        //Added code to called the setters
        setWeight(weight);
        setName(name);
        setType(type);
    }

    // getters
    string getType() { return type; }
    string getName() { return name; }
    int getWeight() { return weight; }

    //Added setter for type
    void setType(string type) { this->type = type; }
    //Added setter for name
    void setName(string name) { this->name = name; }
    // setter for weight
    void setWeight(int weight) { this->weight = weight; }

    //Added the display method in the Animal class to display the animal details
    string display() {
        string printLine = "";
        printLine = "\nAnimal Type: " + this->getType() + ", Animal Name: " + this->getName() + ", Animal Weight: " + to_string(this->getWeight());
        return printLine;
    }
};

// derived class Horse
class Horse : public Animal {
public:
    Horse(string name, int weight) : Animal("horse", name, weight)
    {}
};

// derived class Cow
class Cow : public Animal {
public:
    Cow(string name, int weight) : Animal("cow", name, weight)
    {}
};

// derived class Chicken
class Chicken : public Animal {
public:
    Chicken(string name, int weight) : Animal("chicken", name, weight)
    {}
};

class Barn {
private:
    vector<Animal*> barn;

public:
    Barn();
    void feedAnimal();
    void display();

};

Barn::Barn() {
    srand(time(0)); // this will be srand not rand
    Animal* a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++) {
        a = new Horse("Artax" + to_string(i + 1), rand() % 200 + 1820); // end with semicolon not colon
        barn.push_back(a);

        a = new Cow("Fafnir" + to_string(i + 1), rand() % 250 + 1200); // convert (i+1) to string not (i+)
        barn.push_back(a);

        a = new Chicken("David" + to_string(i + 1), rand() % 2 + 15);
        barn.push_back(a);
    }

}

//Added the display code here, moved the code from inside the Barn constructor
void Barn::display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < barn.size(); i++) {
        cout << barn[i]->display() << " " << " "; //This Displays all the animals
    }
}

void Barn::feedAnimal() {
    int days;// = 0;
    string feed;
    cout << "\nhow many days:";
    cin >> days;
    //Added the code here - Sort of modifications
    //We are looping the vector once, check the time and animal increase the weight, the prior code was looping the vector multiple times for a day and time
    for (int day = 0; day < days;day++) {
        for (int feedtime = 1; feedtime <= 12; feedtime++) {
            feed = to_string(feedtime) + ":00"; // define the type for feed
            cout << "\nThe Time is " << feed << "\n";
            for (int barnNum = 0; barnNum < barn.size();barnNum++) {
                if ((feedtime == 3) && (barn[barnNum]->getType() == "chicken")) {
                    barn[barnNum]->setWeight(barn[barnNum]->getWeight() + 1); // add 1 pound to its weight
                    cout << "\n" << barn[barnNum]->getName() << " " << barn[barnNum]->getType() << " now weighs " << barn[barnNum]->getWeight() << " lbs";
                }

                if ((feedtime == 5) && (barn[barnNum]->getType() == "horse")) {
                    barn[barnNum]->setWeight(barn[barnNum]->getWeight() + 5); // add 5 pound to its weight
                    cout << "\n" << barn[barnNum]->getName() << " " << barn[barnNum]->getType() << " now weighs " << barn[barnNum]->getWeight() << " lbs";
                }

                if ((feedtime == 7) && (barn[barnNum]->getType() == "cow")) {
                    barn[barnNum]->setWeight(barn[barnNum]->getWeight() + 5); // add 5 pound to its weight
                    cout << "\n" << barn[barnNum]->getName() << " " << barn[barnNum]->getType() << " now weighs " << barn[barnNum]->getWeight() << " lbs";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //I need to run the program so a unit of time passes
    //When the time runs, the time will be compared to
    //the animals feeding time. When that feed time passes,
    //The animal gains weight and the new weight is shown.
    int choice;

    cout << "1) Simulate Days" << endl;
    cout << "2) Display Animals" << endl;
    cout << "3) Exit" << endl;
    //Added code to create a Barn object
    Barn myBarn;
    cout << "Choose an option: \n";
    cout << "Enter 1, 2 or 3: ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "\nChoice 1"; //Here we will run feedAnimal
        //Call the feedAnimal() method
        myBarn.feedAnimal();
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "\nChoice 2";
        //Call the display() method
        myBarn.display();
        break;//Here we will display all the animals
    case 3:
        cout << "\nChoice 3"; break;//Here we will exit the program
    default:
        cout << "\nNot 1, 2 or 3"; break;
    }
}
```